# Comparing objects based on partial data

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, compare

Wondering if there is an inexpensive way to compare 2 objects based on one of the objects only containing partial data. Imagine I have the following:

```
var matrix = {
    3: {
        1:2,
        5:20,
        11:3
        8:17
    },
    5: {
        1:3,
        5:18,
        8:17,
        11:4
    },
    6: {
        1:3,
        5:18,
        8:17,
        11:6
    }
};
```

I also have:

```
var data = {
    8:17,
    1:2
};
```

I want to find out which child objects from the `matrix` object are still matches to my `data` object. As you can imagine, I will continue to build up the `data` object until it is the same length as the child objects within the `matrix` (in this case, 4). The ultimate goal will be to find one child object from the `matrix` to match my `data` object. Until that happens, I cut down the possibilities by ignoring any objects in the `matrix` which don't match my partial `data` set.

An object would only be considered a match if all key:value pairs were present. The order does not matter, just the existence of. In the example given here, only the first object from `matrix` (key of 3) would be considered a match. There will always be one match.

I have tried creating a few nested loops, but it gets pretty confusing an intensive. Wondering if there are some methods or techniques out there which I have not come across as of yet.

Can work in plain jane JS or jQuery. Any direction is much appreciated.

Comment: what defines a match? Any first level property of `matrix` that contains the same key/value pair? A set of expected results might help

Comment: Good point. An object would only be a match if it contained all key:value pairs. So in the example above, only the first object (key: 3) would be considered a match.